# Getting 'Segmentation Fault' when running simple string manipulation program

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to learn some C and am having a little bit of trouble with manipulating strings. In trying to learn them, I've decided to make a simple spanish verb conjugator, but I'm getting stuck.  Right now I'm just trying to drop the last 2 non '\0' of the string and then add a 'o' to it. (For example, for an input of "hablar" I want it to output "hablo").  Here's my code. I've tried to be overly detailed in my comments to hopefully aid in figuring out what I'm missing conceptually.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Reimplemented the length function of a string for practice */
int len(char *);
void conjugatePresentAr(char *, char *);

int len(char *arr){
    int l = 0;
    while (*arr++ != '\0'){
        l++;
    }
    return l;
}

void conjugatePresentAr(char *verb, char *output){
    output = verb;
    int i = len(verb);
    while (output < (verb + i -2)){
        *output = *verb;
        output++;
        verb++;
    }
    *output = 'o';
    output++;
    *output = '\0';
}

int main(){
    char input[20];
    scanf("%s", input);
    printf("%s\n",input);
    char conjugated[20];
    conjugatePresentAr(input, conjugated);
    printf("%s\n", conjugated);
    return 0;
}
```

For any input I get Segmentation Fault: 11. I've spent a decent amount of time looking around here and reading through books on pointers but can't quite seem to figure out what I'm messing up. I appreciate your help!

Comment: If you get a segfault, you can see where in the code it faulted (exact details depend on your platform, which you haven't told us, but in general running it under a debugger will take you there).

Comment: @dacrovinunghi thanks bro. Never would have guess that my code sucks. Rather than posting this snarky comment it would actually be more helpful to explain why this is bad/why it is unneeded. I didn't just throw this thing together in like 10 minutes. Believe it or not, I've actually thought about and modified this a lot but I clearly am not grasping the concepts.

Comment: shows a lack of understanding on the difference between a pointer (storage used for memory address storage), what the pointer contains (a specific memory address), and what is contained in the memory the pointer indicates (the contents of that memory address)

Comment: @Speed8ump Thanks for reiterating what I've already said

Comment: Start playing with pointers (with only 2, basics exercices ). Just one look to your code and i see "output = verb" sorry, start with short code.

Comment: Thanks to the person who added the code to the bottom, I was in the process of doing that while you did it. Apologies @RSahu

Comment: Keep in mind that just because function prototypes *let* you specify the type without a name for an argument (`int len(char *)`), doesn't mean you *should*. Sometimes it's better to be explicit. And by "sometimes", I mean "99% of the time".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `conjugatePresentAr()` you have changed the argument `*output`, possibly because you thought that copies the string.

```
output = verb;
```

so the function doesn't write anything to the string you supplied. Then when you print it, it's still an *uninitialised variable*.

Comment: Yes. That's the reason for seg fault.

Comment: Since this is at least a github link rather than a screencap, it's easy enough to edit in (Weather Vane just beat me to it).

Comment: @dacrovinunghi nope: I saw it for  myself before you commented, but it took a minute or two to make my answer. Did you downvote me ?

Comment: @dacrovinunghi Please act civil. If you're going to abuse the downvote privilege for immature/irresponsible reasons, then you don't deserve to use it.

Answer (score 3):

```
int i = len(verb);
while (output < (verb + i -2)){
    *output = *verb;
    output++;
    verb++;
}
```

will keep going forever: you're chasing `(verb + i - 2)` as it recedes into the distance (you increment `verb` inside the loop).

Try something like:

```
char *end = verb + strlen(verb) - 2;
while (output < end) {
    ...
    verb++; /* this doesn't change end */
}
```

(and also fix the bug Weather Vane spotted which I entirely missed).

---

Note: in general, string processing is hard to do well in C, because the built-in facilities are so low-level. It's actually much easier to use C++ with its `string` and `stringstream` facilities.

If you're sticking to C, explicitly tracking length and allocated capacity alongside the char pointer (as the C++ string does for you) is good practice. Oh, and there's no obvious benefit to re-writing `strlen`.

Comment: Ok. Wow, that was a really dumb mistake. Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer and not just belittle my admittedly very poor understanding of C

Comment: Making a dumb mistake doesn't make you dumb - only making the same dumb mistake repeatedly can do that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy strings (char *) by assignment, like you did here:

```
output = verb;
```

What you do here is just change output to **point** at the input string, so any changes made to one of the strings will also apply to the other one - since they both point to the same memory.

you need to explicitly a function for copying the memory - such as strcpy (make sure to supply a null terminated string) or memcpy.

And, regarding your logic, since you don't really check the string for 'ar' in the end, and just assume there is, why not use something a little simpler like this:

```
void conjugatePresentAr(char *verb, char *output) 
{
    strcpy(output,verb);
    int len = strlen(verb);
    output[len - 2] = 'o';
    output[len - 1] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In function conjugatePresentAr() you have alterered the argument *output

```
output = verb;
```

Is an address affectation, not value.
Should reread pointer definition